# Beanstalk node app: How do I redirect https://mypage.com or http://mypage.com to https://www.mypage.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

**What works:**

a) If user types in mypage.com without any http or https, it will route to https://www.mypage.com

b) If user types in http://www.mypage.com then it will redirect to https://www.mypage.com

**What doesnt work:**

If user types in http://mypage.com or https://mypage.com, it will not redirect to https://www.mypage.com

**Current setup:**
I have www.mypage.com as A record in route 53 pointing to my ELB
I have ELB listener set to forward http on port 80 to https port 443 --> no extra listener rules added

Question:
How do I get it to route http://mypage.com or https://mypage.com to redirect or forward to https://www.mypage.com?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pointing mypage.com Alias record to the ELB is the right approach.

However what might be missed in the documentation is if are using an organizational account in AWS and the root account is where you registered the domain, you need to update NS record with that of the NS from the organizational account you are working with.

Lets assume I have Account A (root) and Account B in the organization. In Account B my ns records for mypage.com was not the same as the ns record in Account A for mypage.com. So I had to update Account A to match Account B.

Once I did this, I just pointed mypage.com Alias record in account B to my ELB. I also had a A record for www.mypage.com pointing to same ELB.

Finally, in ELB I forward http to https- and it works!